# Using Dosbox in Ubuntu

Tags: mount

I have installed Dosbox in Ubuntu 14.04.4 so that I can run a Dos database program. The instructions tell me to `z:\mount c: c:\"directory name"\`  which produces an error telling me that the `c:\` drive does not exist.

Problem is that I cannot find a drive named c. The list on the left panel shows drive icons named OS, DATA, 99mb volume, DATA

I have no experience with Ubuntu and so cannot see where I would find a c drive. The dos program that I want to run in Dosbox is located in the drive named OS.

Comment: Which instructions?

Answer (score 4):

The tutorial you are following is for windows but you may follow that as there is not significant change in how dosbox works in Linux (except for path of the files which I have explained below).

There is no 'C:' drive or any other windows drives in Ubuntu. The root directory is '/' (like C: drive in windows). Normally your files are downloaded or saved to /home/**user** or /home/**user**/Desktop where **user** is the name you have given to your account.

Open the directory you want to mount using a file manager(like nautilus) and note down the path shown in the properties of the folder.
Now in dosbox type

```
mount c: <path>
```

Example:

```
mount C: /home/xyz/TC
```

**Additional Info**

If you want the directory to be mounted at dosbox startup.

1. Goto your home folder (i.e. /home/**user**).
2. Open dosbox.conf (It should be there).
3. At the end of the file add these lines, save and close the file.

> ```
> [autoexec]
> mount C: <path>
> ```

Note: Any command under [autoexec] will be executed at startup

**Optional**

You can use '~' instead of '/home/**user**'

Example:

```
mount c ~/TC
```

Comment: what is the mount command in dosbox if I installed (using WINE) a game into "C:\folder\gamefolder" ?

Comment: Find the C drive in .wine folder in home directory.